# How to define multiple filters in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have small matrix **4*4**, I want to filter it with two different filters in TensorFlow (1.8.0). I have an example with one filter (`my_filter`):
I want to change the filter to

```
my_filter = tf.constant([0.2,0.5], shape=[2, 2, 3, 1])
```

One will be **2*2** all `0.25` other **2*2** all `0.5`. But how to set the values?

This is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

import numpy as np
tf.reset_default_graph()
x_shape = [1, 4, 4, 1]
x_val = np.ones(shape=x_shape)
x_val[0,1,1,0]=5
print(x_val)

x_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=x_shape)

my_filter = tf.constant(0.25, shape=[2, 2, 1, 1])
my_strides = [1, 2, 2, 1]
mov_avg_layer= tf.nn.conv2d(x_data, my_filter, my_strides,
padding='SAME', name='Moving_Avg_Window')

# Execute the operations
with tf.Session() as sess:
   #print(x_data.eval())  
   result =sess.run(mov_avg_layer,feed_dict={x_data: x_val})
   print("Filter: " , result)
   print("Filter: " , result.shape)
   sess.close()
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want with `tf.constant([0.2,0.5], shape=[2, 2, 3, 1])`. Could you write how you want to fill the tensor with the values 0.2 and 0.5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First option**

The filter can also be defined as a placeholder

```
filter = tf.placeholder(filter_type, filter_shape)
...
with tf.Session() as sess:
 for i in range (number_filters) :
   result =sess.run(mov_avg_layer,feed_dict={x_data: x_val, filter: filter_val})
```

**Second option**

define a second filter in the graph

```
my_filter = tf.constant(0.25, shape=[2, 2, 1, 1])
my_filter2 = tf.constant(0.5, shape=[2, 2, 1, 1])

mov_avg_layer= tf.nn.conv2d(x_data, my_filter, my_strides,
padding='SAME', name='Moving_Avg_Window')

mov_avg_laye2= tf.nn.conv2d(x_data, my_filter2, my_strides,
padding='SAME', name='Moving_Avg_Window')

...
with tf.Session() as sess:
   result1, result2 =sess.run([mov_avg_layer1, mov_avg_layer2],feed_dict={x_data: x_val})
   sess.close()
```